# Joining tables on complex conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA ( Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 ) AS
  SELECT 'a', 'b',  1, 'ABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'a', 'b',  2, 'DEF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'a', 'b', 15, 'GHI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'c', 'd', 17, 'JKL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'c', 'd', 10, 'MNO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'c', 'd',  6, 'PQR' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE TableB ( Col1, Col2, Col3 ) AS
  SELECT 'a', 'b',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'a', 'b',  4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'a', 'b', 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'c', 'd',  9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'c', 'd', 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'c', 'd',  3 FROM DUAL;
```

The output is 
`A.COL1, A.COL2,B.COL3` AND `A.COL4` such that value of `b.col3` is the maximum value lower than `a.col3`. `TableC` is the output table as below.

```
TableC
+------+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
+------+------+------+------+
| a    | b    |    1 | ABC  |
| a    | b    |    1 | DEF  |
| a    | b    |   12 | GHI  |
| c    | d    |   12 | JKL  |
| c    | d    |    9 | MNO  |
| c    | d    |    3 | PQR  |
+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: _Please_ ditch these HTML tables and show us SQL tables instead.  Format each line with 4 spaces so that it appears as code.

Comment: Why do you have two such similar tables as TableA and TableB? Always same number of rows, same col1 and col2 data etc?

Comment: @jarlh Yes, they are.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I do not know how to show them. Please help me out with any meta how-to links.

Comment: @ChiragGandhi The simplest way (and most useful to answerers) to present SQL data is to give the DDL & DML statements used to create the tables & data; that way people can copy/paste it directly into an SQL client and quickly answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it is simpler to use a correlated sub-query rather than to join the tables:

**Query**:

```
SELECT A.Col1,
       A.Col2,
       ( SELECT MAX( B.Col3 )
         FROM   TableB B
         WHERE  A.Col1 = B.Col1
         AND    A.Col2 = B.Col2
         AND    A.Col3 > B.Col3 ) AS Col3,
       A.Col4
FROM   TableA A;
```

**Output**:

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
---- ---- ---- ----
a    b    NULL ABC
a    b       1 DEF
a    b      12 GHI
c    d      12 JKL
c    d       9 MNO
c    d       3 PQR
```

If you want the first row to have `COL3` to equal `1` then you need to use `>=` rather than `>` (but this was not the logic described in your text).

If you want to filter out the `NULL` row then use:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ( ... above query ... )
WHERE  Col3 IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do a `JOIN` for col1, col2 and col4 values. Have a correlated sub-query that returns that max TableB.col3 less than TableA.col3:

```
select ta.col1, ta.col2, (select max(col3) from TableB
                          where col1 = t1.col1 and col2 = t1.col2 and col3 < ta.col3),
       tb.col4
from TableA ta
  join TableB tb on ta.col1 = tb.col1 and ta.col2 = tb.col2
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to join on an easy join clause and deal with the rest by a where clause. This query works on your example:

```
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, b1.col3, a.col4
FROM a JOIN b b1 ON a.col1 = b1.col1 AND a.col2 = b1.col2
WHERE b1.col3 <= a.col3 
  AND NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT * FROM b c 
     WHERE c.col1 = b1.col1 AND c.col2 = b1.col2 
        AND c.col3 > b1.col3 AND c.col3 <= a.col3
     )
```